# Extract part of a string from a filename

Tags: r, import, gsub

I am importing multiple excel file and I want to create a vector with the names of each file, which I then want to use to perform some further operations.

Here is a minimum working example, assuming that I am importing two excel files:

```
Excel file name 1: x1_company_90.xls
Excel file name 2: gghi_company_90.xls
```

I want to create a vector with the following parts of the file names once I read them in r:

**expected result:**

```
names<-c ("x1","gghi")
```

Comment: use `list.files(path = "this/is my path"), pattern = ".xls"`

Comment: @patL this is want I want, but instead of getting the first part of the file name into a vector a get the last i.e. "_company_90". I instead want "x1" and "gghi"

Comment: Try: `gsub("_company_90.xls", "", c("x1_company_90.xls","gghi_company_90.xls"), fixed = TRUE)`

Comment: @zx8754 yes, using the list.files and what you suggested it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using *gsub*:

```
myFileNames <- list.files(path = "my/path", pattern = "*_company_90.xls")

# example file list:
# myFileNames <- c("x1_company_90.xls","gghi_company_90.xls")

myNames <- gsub("_company_90.xls", "", myFileNames, fixed = TRUE)
myNames
# [1] "x1"   "gghi"
```